# Setting the name of a ConfigurationProperty dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, config, configuration-files

I'm developping a C# application. Everything is configurable using a **.config** file so I'm using the `System.Configuration` namespace to deserialize this file.

I create `ConfigurationPropertyCollection` and `ConfigurationProperty` elements in base of the `circustances` and use the `ConfigurationProperty` attribute to decorate a property and inform the .NET that that property is an element into the configuration file.

Ex..

**C#**

```
[ConfigurationProperty(nameof(Times), IsRequired = true)]
public TimesConfigurationElement Times => (TimesConfigurationElement)(base[nameof(Times)]);
```

So far nothing relevant. But let's suppose we have this configuration fragment:

**.config file fragment**

```
<Actions>
   <Action Type="WriteFile">
      <WriteFile Append="Hello World" InFile="C:\File.txt"/>
   </Action>
   <Action Type="ExecuteCommandLine">
      <ExecuteCommandLine Text="shutdown -r"/>
   </Action>
</Actions>
```

As you can see, there is a `ActionsConfigurationElementCollection` containing Actions. But each action can contain different type of sub-node in base of its Type attribute.
So, if I try to translate it into classes:

**C#**

```
public class ActionsConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
     public ConfigurationElement NewElement() {return new ActionConfigurationElement(); }
}

public class ActionConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty(nameof(Type))]
    public string Type => (string)base[nameof(Type)];

    [ConfigurationProperty(Type)] -- I get an error here
    public IConfigurableAction Action
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type == "WriteFileAction") return (WriteFileAction)base["WriteFile"];
            else if ... and so on;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line `[ConfigurationProperty(Type)]` because naturally the `ConfigurationProperty` constructor cannot see the Type property and need a reference to access to this non-static property.

So how can I manage this? Have a configuration element that depends on the previous configuration? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You will probably need to create a `WriteFileActionElement` and a `ExecuteCommandLineActionElement` that all derive from a base `ActionConfigurationElement`... Otherwise you could pick a different serialization format.

Comment: Hi... Yes, I've already done them and return the correct instance on the getter method. What I don't know is to manage the ConfigurationProperty attribute in this case :( Or I could inject the name of the COnfigurationProperty via reflection but seems a dirty solution to me

Comment: As stated above it may be more workable to have <Actions><WriteFile…/><ExecuteCommandLine…/></Actions>